# Letting the world know about your contract

Tags: contract-design

I'm currently struggling with some conceptual ideas of Ethereum, which I hope some of you might enlighten me on.

Say, I want to offer a contract which insures Spanish olive farmers against a bad harvest. Creating such a contract will be easy enough, but how will I let the farmers know about this contract. (For now just let's assume these farmers are very tech savvy and know all about Ethereum and block chain tech.)

Of course I want to use the Ethereum block chain to let them know and not some off chain mechanisms. What could be done, I suppose, is creating some kind of a master contract, that has an event "New Insurance offer" which also communicates the necessary data.

But would such a master contract eventually run out of gas? Can a contract be refueled?

So in short, would a master contract solve this issue, or are there better ways to do the above?

Thanks for answering,
Coen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, how would a Spanish olive farmer know about the master contract, either? Realistically, it's better to just point your customers directly at your smart contract than to attempt to use on-chain methods to spread the news. If there are multiple kinds of insurance from different sub-contracts, then it may make more sense to have a master contract.

Contracts don't run out of gas--every time you use a contract, you, the user, provide gas for that one transaction.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was indeed thinking of a bundle of different flavours of sub-contracts and only communicate once. As I see now, I misinterpreted the gas concept. I thought you provided a contract with 'a full tank' and then every time a function was called the gas was taken out of this tank.